# How to run a docker image on Azure devops agent with docker task V2?

Tags: docker, azure-devops

It's easy with docker task V1. It can run docker image from Azure Container Registry.

But with docker task V2, I can't find a way to run an image.

If I push the image with V2 and try to run it with V1, I can't set the 'latest' tag when I push with V2, but I need it when I run it with V1.

There must be a way to do it with docker task V2 I assume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `docker task v2`, in fact, you can input the `run` command **manually** in that blank:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: run
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: Merlindockerhub
    repository: 650301
    command: run
    arguments: '{image}'
```

---

For v2, we provide the support for inputting commands **manually**, no matter you configure it with UI or YAML. Both of them are all support.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I'm using yaml. And the Acceptable values for 'command' are: buildAndPush/build/push/login/logout. Ref:: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops

Comment: @AllenZhang, What we did not document is for docker v2, we also support input command manually. For run command, you can input it directly, no matter it is configured with UI or YAML. You can have a try on your side to confirm this.

Comment: @AllenZhang, Or you can have look at this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4021#issuecomment-487250090 He is one of our team. **The command input can be specified as 'run' and any arguments that are to be passed onto docker binary can be done so through the 'arguments' input directly.**

Comment: It might be a good idea to document it? This definitely deserves some spaces on the documentation page, right?

Comment: @AllenZhang, Of course it is. So do you mind report it to our document team in [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues)? Or I could help for contact our document team via internal method.